# Import-CSV adn set attributes only for non-empty values

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have such CSV

```
EMP_ID DEP_ID LOGIN_AD
0102   042    jane.doe
0103          john.doe
0104   042    
0105   046    john.smith
```

I'd like to create script that will import this csv and next set values on the user account like this extenssionattribute1 = EMP_ID and extenssionattribute2 = DEP_ID. Main thing is that script should skip empty values. In example below script should set on the jane.doe account extenssionattribute1 = 0102, extenssionattribute2 = 042, but on john.doe only extenssionattribute1 = 0103, script should skip row without LOGIN_AD.

For now I'm trying something like this:

```
Import-CSV "c:\test.csv" | foreach-object {
$adLogin = @($_.LOGIN_AD) | where-object{$_};
if (Get-AdUser -Identity $adLogin) 
{
if ($_.EMP_ID) {Set-admUser $adLogin -Replace @{extensionAttribute1 = $_.EMP_ID} 
if ($_.DEP_ID) {Set-admUser $adLogin -Replace @{extensionAttribute2 = $_.DEP_ID} 
}
```

but I still got error when LOGIN_AD is empty. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the CSV you need to specifiy the delimiter as a space, then you need to select objects where the LOGIN_AD is not empty, finally, do what you need in a ForEach-Object loop, also don't forget to load the properties:

```
Import-CSV "c:\test.csv" -Delimiter ' ' | where-object{$_.LOGIN_AD -ne ""}| foreach-object {
    $adLogin = $_.LOGIN_AD

    if (Get-AdUser -Identity $adLogin -properties extensionAttribute1,extensionAttribute2) 
    {
        if ($_.EMP_ID) {Set-admUser $adLogin -Replace @{extensionAttribute1 = $_.EMP_ID} }
        if ($_.DEP_ID) {Set-admUser $adLogin -Replace @{extensionAttribute2 = $_.DEP_ID} }
    }
}
```